# In Ruby on rails, how to show loading image till an action completes executing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application, where users will be redirected to our site from a parent website. We will be getting the user's details by SAML process. Based on the details received, if the user is new user,the user will be created. So the action sessions/consume takes some time to process.Is it possible to show a loading image or any image until the action completes? So that users will not see blank screen.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways you can do this. I think the easiest would probably to use JavaScript on the client side to make the "loading..." image appear when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: The link appears in the parent portal and when they click the link, our site is opening in new window. Cant the image be shown from our site?

Comment: Sure. Load a simple HTML page first with a floating "Loading..." image. Use an AJAX call to retrieve the contents of the "slow" page. When the AJAX call returns, replace the contents of the "loading" page with what was returned from the "slow" page.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is using jquery in rails.In Rails after submitting form if u want to show loader till action completes.. below is the simple example::                                  `<script type="text/javascript">  $("#me").click(function(){
  $("#img").css("display","block");
});  </script>  <%=submit_tag "Approve",:id=>"me"%>  <p id="img" style="display:none;"><%= image_tag 'loader2.gif' %></p>`